# Adds same record multiple times to database instead of just once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I have an issue with php script, it adds more records than it suppose to. I have big table with several "subtables" with people's salaries and its distribution:

## Name # PayRate # Distribution # Annual

John Smith # 10,000 # 20.00% # 50,000 # edit # delete
Peter Pan # 100,000 # 100.00% # 100,000 # edit # delete

### Add new person

When you click on new person, form pop up, you type all information, add person to database, ajax returns information and add person to the end of the list. here is the problem, when I click in one "subtable" add person, it adds one person and prints correctly, but when I go to second "subtable", and add a person, it will add person two times (insert two same records to database), if I click add person on third "subtable" it will add one record three times... It should add record only once. Here is my js script:

```
$('.addbtt').on('click', function(){
    value= "";
    document.getElementById("updform").reset();
    var glnumber = $(this).parent().parent().find('#glno').text();
    var objid = glnumber.substring(7,12);
    value += glnumber.substring(10,12);
    if(objid=='51001'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - Full time");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    }else if(objid=='51002'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - Part time");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    }else if(objid=='51009'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - GA");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    }else if(objid=='51010'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - GE");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    };

    $('#updform').submit(function(){
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.post('includes/updatesal.php',formData,processData);
        function processData(data){
            if(value == 01){
                $('#addperson1').before(data);
            }else if(value == 02){
                $('#addperson2').before(data);
            }else if(value == 09){
                $('#addperson3').before(data);
            }else if(value == 10){
                $('#addperson4').before(data);
            }else{
                alert("Your are doing something you shouldn't! :)") 
            };
        }; //end of processData
        return false;
    });
});
```

I think the problem is with my "add person button" because it adds also two records to the database. Here is my php function:

```
$insertSQL1 = "INSERT INTO salaries (gl_number,name,pay_rate,distribution,annual)
                VALUES ('".$glnumber."','".$name."','".$payRate."','".$dist."','".$annual."')";
        $insertSQL1 .= "; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS RECORD_ID";    
        $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query(Database::GetInstance()->databaseConnection, $insertSQL1);
        # IF THERE IS AN ERROR
        if(!$stmt1){
            echo "Error";   
        }else{
            $id = Database::GetInstance()->LastInsertId($stmt1);
        }
        # IF ALL QUERIES WERE SUCCSESSFUL, COMMIT THE TRANSACTION, OTHERWISE ROLLBACK
        if($stmt1 && !$errors){
            sqlsrv_commit(Database::GetInstance()->databaseConnection);
            # FREE THE STATEMENT
            Database::GetInstance()->FreeDBStatement($stmt1);
```

I am trying to figure this out for a week now, can anybody help?

Comment: Do you use a browser debugger (like firebug)? do you see two posts?

Comment: They have given the correct answer. I wanna give you a suggestion: do not use string concatenation to produce the sql, this will cause sql injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by your `.submit()` event handler being *inside* the `.click()` event handler -- so you're creating a new, identical `.submit()` handler with each click.

To fix, just take the `.submit()` handler out of there:

```
$('.addbtt').on('click', function(){
    value= "";
    document.getElementById("updform").reset();
    var glnumber = $(this).parent().parent().find('#glno').text();
    var objid = glnumber.substring(7,12);
    value += glnumber.substring(10,12);
    if(objid=='51001'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - Full time");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    }else if(objid=='51002'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - Part time");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    }else if(objid=='51009'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - GA");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    }else if(objid=='51010'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - GE");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    };
});

$('#updform').submit(function(){
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('includes/updatesal.php',formData,processData);
    function processData(data){
        if(value == 01){
            $('#addperson1').before(data);
        }else if(value == 02){
            $('#addperson2').before(data);
        }else if(value == 09){
            $('#addperson3').before(data);
        }else if(value == 10){
            $('#addperson4').before(data);
        }else{
            alert("Your are doing something you shouldn't! :)") 
        };
    }; //end of processData
    return false;
});
```

Comment: $('#updform').submit(function(){
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('includes/updatesal.php',formData,processData);
    function processData(data){...

Comment: It should work fine. Are you adding that form dynamically? Try replacing `$('#updform').submit(function(){` with `$(document).on('submit', '#updform', function(){`

Comment: $(document).on('submit', '#updform', function(){}

works... I don't understand why other one didn't

Comment: You must have created the `.submit` event handler (in JS) before the `#updform` element was created (in HTML). Using `$(document).on('submit,'#updform` [delegates the event](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to the `document` instead. You might want to give `.addbtt` the same treatment.

Comment: That's is exactly what happened, form is loaded using .load() so it is created after .submit

Answer (score 0):

Also You can move form clear script to inside of "submit handler as well"

```
// No need following on click handler, if button is submit
$('.addbtt').on('click', function(){

});

$('#updform').submit(function(){
value= "";
    document.getElementById("updform").reset();
    var glnumber = $(this).parent().parent().find('#glno').text();
    var objid = glnumber.substring(7,12);
    value += glnumber.substring(10,12);
    if(objid=='51001'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - Full time");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    }else if(objid=='51002'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - Part time");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    }else if(objid=='51009'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - GA");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    }else if(objid=='51010'){
        $('.modal-title').html("Add person - GE");
        $('#glnumber').empty().val(glnumber);
    };

    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('includes/updatesal.php',formData,processData);
    function processData(data){
        if(value == 01){
            $('#addperson1').before(data);
        }else if(value == 02){
            $('#addperson2').before(data);
        }else if(value == 09){
            $('#addperson3').before(data);
        }else if(value == 10){
            $('#addperson4').before(data);
        }else{
            alert("Your are doing something you shouldn't! :)") 
        };
    }; //end of processData
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Who said the `.addbtt` button was part of the `#updform`?

Comment: @Blazemonger, Please note comment (//No need following on click handler, if button is submit) in code